# Task parallelization and data synchronization in a pipeline

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I have 5 independent components A, B, C, D, E, where A and B are producing data, C and D are processing both of the data from A and B, E will visualize the results from C and D.

The most straightforward way to implement this pipeline is put them all in one thread:

```
while (keep_running)
    A->B->C->D->E
```

But C and D could be in parallel to be more efficient. And So may be the components A and B.

```
while (keep_running)
    {A && B could be in parallel} -> {C && D in parallel} -> E
```

I wonder what is the efficient way to implement this.

Thanks!

Update: Sorry for the unclearence.

Let me just formulate my question in a pseudo codes manner.

```
// keep_running is just a bool, could be updated to terminate the loop 
while (keep_running) 
      run A; // produce data
      run B; // produce data 
      run C; // processing data from A and B 
      run D; // processing data from A and B
      run E; // visualize results from B and C

while (keep_running)
      create_thread ta to run A;
      create thread tb to run B;
      ta.run();
      tb.run();
      join ta and tb;
      create thread tc to C;
      create thread td for D;
      tc.run();
      td.run();
      join tc and td;
      run E; 
      destroy ta,tb,tc,td;

// I think above implementation is not efficient, because create and destroy threads every time
// I wonder if there're some efficient implementation like:
create thread ta,tb,tc,td;
while (keep_running)
      ta.run_once();
      tb.run_once();
      wait ta and tb; // A and B finish a round and go to sleep.
      tc.run_once();
      td.run_once();
      wait tc and td;
      run E;
destroy ta, tb, tc, td

// Or other more efficient way ?
```

I don't have much experience in threading, apologize for the unclear issue, and hope someone could give me some hints that I could figure this out.

Thanks.

Comment: Please select *one* of either C or C++.

Comment: @MikeCAT Why ? I could accept answers in either C or C++.

Comment: Is that just me, or the question is completely unclear without context?

Comment: @Jeff The arrow here is only about the execution order, not data flow.

Comment: @blackball: Because C and C++ are different languages. Your question is already too broad for one language. But it might be narrowed down if you pick one of them.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I picked too broad, but I could have flipped a coin.

Comment: (one of) the easiest way(s) is openmp.

Comment: @Olaf, Mike, I think it's legit to tag a question with multiple languages if the question is about algorithm in either of them...

Comment: It's umm.. broad, I think, its unclear too:(  'while (keep_running)' what keep running?  Makes no sense.

Comment: Ironically if this question is asked twice with C and C++ tags respectively then it definitely would be marked as duplicate of each other.

Comment: @Olaf it's code for C/C++

Comment: @Olaf That's a typo, but `C+=` is indeed another language.

Comment: There is a language-agnostic tag, IIRC.

Comment: @user3528438: No kidding? Link?

Comment: @Olaf https://github.com/ErisBlastar/cplusequality

Comment: @user3528438: Reminds me of Vatical (not sure if there is an English description somewhere).

Comment: @Olaf postfix operator has higher precedence than multiplicative operator.

Comment: @Olaf: But it would never be interpreted as `1/++`.

Comment: @Olaf *which* language?

Comment: @Olaf, no `C/C++`, according to precedence rules, would be evaluated as `C/(C++)`. Didn't we already cover this?

Comment: @EOF: Hmm, then it would be `C/C++` -> `1/C(++ - 1)`? - too complicated, I'll stick with the UB. Let's clean this up.

Answer (score 0):

Create two thread for A and B, put a barrier after them so that you don't run into conflict.
Create two thread for C &&D, process, put barrier
Finish E. L